# set proxy configuration in c++ code

Tags: c++, proxy

I have a  raspberry running Yocto.
I'm making a code to setup de proxy configuration of the OS connection.

An example of the conde that I'm using is the following

```
int main(void)
{
   system("unset http_proxy");
   command = "export http_proxy=\"http://hostname.com\"";
   system(command.c_str());
}
```

The solution on code is not working, however, if I input in a terminal the same command, it works.

What can be the problem?

Comment: A unix process can set environment variable only for itself and its children. You have to set the proxy in a startup / initialization script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can be the problem?

`system()` creates a sub-process. So changing the `http_proxy`environment variable with a system call doesn't affect the calling process.

You may try to change the environment variable using `setenv()`, and then `fork()` and continue in the child process to do whatever you need with the new proxy settings.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your answer, but I have a set of programs running, and what i need to do is set the proxy settings for the runining software. Is there a way to do this? or set the proxy as a global parameter for the OS??.

Comment: @Ricardo IIRC there is a configuration you can set to do this systemwide (needs at least a restart of the user session). Not sure what exactly to do for YOCTO.